# Error de llave duplicada Entity Framework SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Estoy diseñando una aplicación pequeña con Entity Framework y SQL, al ingresar el primer registro toma el valor de un cuadro de texto y lo agrega, pero cuando va a ingresar el segundo me aparece un error de llave duplicada: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Empresa__3214EC07D9E284DD'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Empresa'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.'"

Habrá alguna forma de limpiar el datacontext o algo así?, dejo el código .cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext dataContext;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string miConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRUD_LINQ.Properties.Settings.CRUD_LINQConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(miConexion);
        }

        private void InsertaEmpresa(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //dataContext.Dispose(Empresa);
           

            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(CuadroBusqueda.Text)))
            {
                Empresa nuevaEmpresa = new Empresa();
                nuevaEmpresa.Nombre = CuadroBusqueda.Text;
                dataContext.Empresa.InsertOnSubmit(nuevaEmpresa);
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                Principal.ItemsSource = dataContext.Empresa;

               
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ingrese datos");
                CuadroBusqueda.Focus();
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El error es claro, estas duplicando la pk, la cual debe ser unica

Comment: Exacto, ejecuto la aplicación e inserta, al volver a ejecutarla me sale el error.

Comment: Lo siento, me doy cuenta que fui extremadamente poco claro en mi mensaje anterior. El problema parece pasar por la base de datos (no por C#). Como no colocaste el modelo no me es posible decirte con seguridad lo que pasa. Pero generalmente este error aparece por olvidar colocar el Id auto incrementable cuando este Id es auto generado.

Comment: Hola Anthony, podrías decir si alguna respuesta te resultó útil, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero me parece que no estás usando **Entity Framework**, sino **Linq to SQL**, son dos tecnologías distintas de acceso a datos.

Segundo debes revisar si en tu entidad el **campo Id** lo marcaste como único y autoincrementable.

Y tercero siguiendo la lógica de tu respuesta tu código de inserción deberia quedar como:

```
if(dataContext.Empresa.Count() == 0)
{
    contador = 1;
}
else
{
    contador += dataContext.Empresa.OrderBy(e => e.id).Select(e => e.id).LastOrDefault() + 1;
}

Empresa nuevaEmpresa = new Empresa();
nuevaEmpresa.Nombre = CuadroBusqueda.Text;
nuevaEmpresa.Id = contador;
dataContext.Empresa.InsertOnSubmit(nuevaEmpresa);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Esta línea:

```
contador += dataContext.Empresa.OrderBy(e => e.id).Select(e => e.id).LastOrDefault() + 1;
```

Garantiza que la nueva entidad a insertar tenga un **id** que sea consecutivo al último que se había insertado, de esta forma puedes cerrar tu aplicacion y volver a entrar y no perderás la consecución de los ids.

**Nota:** Si tu entidad tiene el **campo id** correctamente configurado con las propiedades de autoincremento y de llave primaria, no te haría falta gestionar tu mismo la generación de los ids.

Answer (score -2):

Me tocó que l aaplicación agregue el id, en vez de que sea autoincremental, mediante un contador y una variable sw. Dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve:

```
namespace CRUD_LINQ
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext dataContext;
        int contador = 0;
        bool sw = true;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string miConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRUD_LINQ.Properties.Settings.CRUD_LINQConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(miConexion);
        }

        private void InsertaEmpresa(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            

            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(CuadroBusqueda.Text)))
            {
                //Empresa nuevaEmpresa = new Empresa();
                //nuevaEmpresa.Nombre = CuadroBusqueda.Text;
                //dataContext.Empresa.InsertOnSubmit(nuevaEmpresa);
                //dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                //Principal.ItemsSource = dataContext.Empresa;

                

                if (sw)
                {
                    Empresa nuevaEmpresa = new Empresa();
                    nuevaEmpresa.Nombre = CuadroBusqueda.Text;
                    dataContext.Empresa.InsertOnSubmit(nuevaEmpresa);
                    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                    Principal.ItemsSource = dataContext.Empresa;
                    sw = false;
                }
                if(sw == false){

                    contador += 1;
                    Empresa nuevaEmpresa = new Empresa();
                    nuevaEmpresa.Nombre = CuadroBusqueda.Text;
                    nuevaEmpresa.Id = contador;
                    dataContext.Empresa.InsertOnSubmit(nuevaEmpresa);
                    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                    Principal.ItemsSource = dataContext.Empresa;
                }

                

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ingrese datos");
                CuadroBusqueda.Focus();
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto no soluciona nada, al reiniciar la aplicación pierdes el valor de "contador"

Comment: Tu respuesta es incorrecta, coincido con @Yussef